# can I change the UV editor when colour blind?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have Deuteranopes(red-green colour blindness) and wondering if its possible to change the UV range in the UV editor?

Comment: what do you mean by the UV range? The generated UV squares image?

Comment: The colour spectrum that's used on the UV map in the editor. Yes the different colours of the faces, how they use different shades of blue through to red. I find it hard to see some of the orange-red and greens. Would it be possible to change it to greyscale? Thanks for the reply

Comment: i think you can change it by the themes options

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that I know of to change what blender generates from these options without editing the code and creating a custom build.

This would however make a good feature request and it would be worth trying to get in contact with some of the devs and seeing if they can help.

That said their is a fairly simple workaround. If you want a greyscale version, you can just save the image out of blender and use your preferred image editing software to convert it to greyscale. Then whenever you want to check your UVs, just load this converted image from disc rather than using blender's generated options.

Comment: thanks for the idea about how to get to greyscale. Yea I'll pursue putting a request in to the devs and hopefully it gets picked up.